# Command line tools to do a diff of csv/tsv files?

Tags: command-line, diff, csv

I work on a bioinformatics tool that produces large TSV files with many (~100) and long (~5-200 char) columns. Getting a whole line from a normal `diff` is overwhelming. It's more important to have the exact column that changes.

Googling "csv-diff", "csvdiff", "tsv-diff", "tsvdiff" returned two maintained tools that seem quite decent and are moderately popular (100+ stars on Github):

- **csv-diff**: https://github.com/simonw/csv-diff (Python based, auto-detects separator, nice line-based output)
- **csvdiff**: https://github.com/aswinkarthik/csvdiff (Go based, standalone binary)

I was wondering if there are any other tools out there that I may have missed.

Comment: What are you missing with the two candidates you found that keeps you from using them? Note that pure list questions are [considered off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154) at all SE sites. So could you please outline your requirements (especially those the two candidates miss)? Thanks!